# C++: Implementation concerning linked list

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I keep on getting a compiler error for one of my functions.

```
LinkedList.hpp:81: error: `template<class T> class LinkedList' used without template parameters
LinkedList.hpp:81: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
LinkedList.hpp:81: error: expected `;' before '*' token
```

But the thing is I have an constructor, destructor, and type conversion. I'm pretty sure that the implementation is wrong

```
// This is the function i keep on getting an error for
template <class T>
ListNode* LinkedList<T>::find(int pos)//Finds the position of an item
{
    if(pos < 1)
        return NULL; //If pos is less than one then find returns NULL because pos is a illegal value.
    else
    {
        ListNode *temp = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
            temp = temp -> next;
        return temp;
    } 
}

//The class 
template <class T>
class LinkedList : public ABCList<T> {
private:
    //T    a [LIST_MAX];

    struct ListNode
    {
        T data; // List item
        ListNode *next; //Pointer to next node
    };

    int  size;
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *find(int pos);

public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(LinkedList &other);
    ~LinkedList();
    virtual bool isEmpty () = 0;
    virtual int  getLength () = 0;
    virtual void insert (int pos, T item) = 0;
    virtual T    remove (int pos) = 0;
    virtual T    retrieve (int pos) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Where is the code where you are you creating a LinkedList object?

Comment: line 81 is `code`template <class T>
ListNode* LinkedList<T>::find(int pos)

Comment: You have to put the class declaration before the definition of ListNode* LinkedList<T>::find(int pos)

Comment: i did that. I just put it that way here so you can see right away what i was having trouble with.

Comment: I think you will have trouble returning a private nested type, ListNode.

Answer (score 2):

1. Why create a linked list when the standard library provides one? `std::list` is a double-linked list.
2. Can you rewrite `ListNode*` to `typename LinkedList<T>::ListNode*` in the `find()` definition
3. You will have to choose whether you want the user to be able to manipulate `ListNode`, (in which case you should declare it as public), or if it is part of the implementation (in which case you might want to create an iterator of some sort).

---

> I still got the same error

Was the definition of `find()` located on top of the declaration of the `LinkedList` class, as presented in the question? If that is the case you should swap them around.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see is that ListNode is defined in LinkedList, so has to be qualified that way:

```
template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::ListNode* LinkedList<T>::find(int pos) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: here is the constructor and destructor and copy                            `code`Template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() //Default constructor
{
 size = 0;
 head = NULL;
}

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(LinkedList &other) //Copy Constructor
{
 for(int i = 1; i < other.getLength(); i++)
  insert(i, other.retrieve(i));
}

template <class T>//Deconstructor
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
 while(!isEmpty ())
  remove(1);
}`code`

Comment: Perhaps post it as part of your question? You can edit it, and it would be much easier for others to read.